# Regex to capture everything after optional token

Tags: regex, pcre

I have fields which contain data in the following possible formats (each line is a different possibility):

```
AAA - Something Here  
AAA - Something Here - D  
Something Here
```

Note that the first group of letters (AAA) can be of varying lengths.

What I am trying to capture is the "Something Here" or "Something Here - D" (if it exists) using PCRE, but I can't get the Regex to work properly for all three cases. I have tried:

`- (.*)` which works fine for cases 1 and 2 but obviously not 3;

`(?<= - )(.*)` which also works fine for cases 1 and 2;

`(?! - )(.+)| - (.+)` works for cases 2 and 3 but not 1.

I feel like I'm on the verge of it but I can't seem to crack it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: I realized that I was unclear in my requirements. If there is a trailing " - D" (the letter in the data is arbitrary but should only be a single character), that needs to be captured as well.

Comment: Can "Something Here" contain a "-"?

Comment: @Sweeper - yes, I realized that was part of the requirement. Basically regardless of the second hyphen's existence it has to capture everything right of the first hyphen (if it exists). I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the patterns that you tried:

- `- (.*)`This pattern will match the first occurrence of  `-`  followed by matching the rest of the line. It will match too much for the second example as the `.*` will also match the second occurrence of  `-`
- `(?<= - )(.*)`This pattern will match the same as the first example without the  `-`  as it asserts that is should occur directly to the left
- `(?! - )(.+)| - (.+)` This pattern uses a negative lookahead which asserts what is directly to the right is not `(?! - )`. As none of the example start with  `-` , the whole line will be matched directly after the negative lookahead due to `.+` and the second part after the alternation `|` will not be evaluated

---

If the first group of letters can be of varying length, you could make the match either specific matching 1 or more uppercase characters `[A-Z]+` or 1+ word characters `\w+`.

To get a more broad match, you could match 1 or more non whitespace characters using `\S+`

```
^(?:\S+\h-\h)?\K\S+(?:\h(?!-\h)\S+)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\S+\h-\h)?` Optionally match the first group of non whitespace chars followed by `-` between horizontal whitespace chars
- `\K` Clear the match buffer (Forget what is currently matched)
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\h(?!-\h)` Match a horizontal whitespace char and assert what is directly to the right is not `-` followed by another horizontal whitespace char
  - `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times to match more "words" separated by spaces

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eKs7MP/1)

**Edit**

To match an optional hyphen and trailing single character, you could add an optional non capturing group `(?:-\h\S\h*)?$` and assert the end of the string if the pattern should match the whole string:

```
^(?:\S+\h-\h)?\K\S+(?:\h(?!-\h)\S+)*\h*(?:-\h\S\h*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NhWzaY/1)

Comment: This was a spectacular answer and I appreciate the breakdown of why the ones I used didn't work; in particular the third one, because I couldn't work out why the negative lookahead seemed to be not evaluated by the engine (looking at the debug feature of regex101.com). Unfortunately I realized I missed a requirement - if there is a trailing hyphen and letter (second case) that trailing hyphen and letter must also be captured. I have edited my question.

Comment: @RyanJ I have added an update to account for that trailing hyphen and letter. If it should be a letter, you could also use `[A-Z]` instead of `\S`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?:.*? - )?\K.*?(?= - | *$)
^(?:.*?\h-\h)?\K.*?(?=\h-\h|\h*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yotunE/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
  -`(?:.*? - )?` - an optional non-capturing group matching any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first `space-space`
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?= - | *$)` - `space-space` or 0+ spaces till the end of string should follow  immediately on the right.

Note that `\h` matches any horizontal whitespace chars.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer and a great explanation, however, I realized that I missed a requirement. It must also match "Something Here - D" e.g. if there is a trailing hyphen + letter, that must be captured as well. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @RyanJ `^(?:.*? - )?\K.*?(?= - \p{L}$| *$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/yotunE/3)) / `^(?:.*?\h-\h)?\K.*?(?=\h-\h\p{L}$|\h*$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/yotunE/4))?

Comment: @RyanJ If it is not what you expect, please drop a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:[A-Z]+ - \K)?.*\S
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/PTFsjA/1)

Since *"Something Here"* can be anything, there's no reason to specially describe the eventual last letter in the pattern. You don't need something more complicated.

With this pattern I assume that you are not interested by the trailing spaces, that's why I ended it with `\S`. If you want to keep them, remove the `\S` and change the previous quantifier to `+`.

Comment: This is a much simpler answer. Beautiful.