# Regex: Capture everything after first colon if colon exists otherwise capture everything

Tags: regex

Using regex alone, I am having trouble capturing things after a field entry that comes in one of three ways:

```
Address: 123 Test Lane, City St
Address:123 Test Lane, City St
123 Test Lane, City St
```

I need to extract only the address, name, other info.

I found
[Regex to capture everything after optional token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825527/regex-to-capture-everything-after-optional-token)

and made a simpler regex `^(?:.*:\s?)?\K.+` that works but the system I'm using does not support the `\K` operator. I'm hoping I'm not out of options here.

Comment: Try `[^:\n]+$`. If necessary add `(?m)`: `(?m)[^:\n]+$`

Comment: Where are you working in? What is the environment? Maybe there is a simpler option.

Comment: Can't you just replace `^Address:\s*` with nothing?

Comment: Its a GUI I don't have control over. I don't know the backend they are using to process the regex unfortunately.

Comment: [^:\n]+$ is working except for Address: 123 Test Lane, City St it grabs the leading space. is there a way to correct this?

Comment: @JvdV I answered a question like that before, when the OP had `\G` and `\K` , but a conversion question was downvoted, closed and deleted  [here (see only for 10k+ users)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69082757/convert-regex-php-to-javascript/69085019#69085019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
[^:\s][^:\n]*$
```

*Details*:

- `[^:\s]` - any char other than `:` and whitespace
- `[^:\n]*` - zero or more chars other than `:` and LF
- `$` - end of string / line (if multiline mode is turned on).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/khWrla/1).

Comment: Maybe swap `[^:\s]` for a word-boundary?

Comment: @JvdV OP asked to get rid of the whitespace at the start, so it seemed logical to use a whitespace based boundary here. Word boundaries match more specific contexts, and probably will work, too, but we'd need exact specs from OP. The `\b[^:\n]+$` might work even better than `[^:\s][^:\n]*$`, but we can't say that without seeing more test cases.

Comment: This removes the whitespace but breaks the test case with no field name
123 Test Lane, City St is not found

Comment: @ryanq.feeney What breaks the test case? It is [matched fine](https://regex101.com/r/khWrla/1) with the current regex.

Comment: I lied. This is working. Thank you so much!!!